# WSO2 SCIM2 Schema data types

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, scim2

We are going to add some attributes into scim2-schema-extension.config, but we can't find list of available data types for this config.
In the config we have found some types: boolean, string, complex, datetime. What other data types can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the data types defined in SCIM specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643.html#section-2.3

Comment: Thats all i need, thanks a lot